# Can a activity be started by not using an intent and how many activities can I add to my manifest ?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I know this is the simplest question but need to clear some doubts.In how many ways an activity can be started other than Intents ? Also, How many Activities can we add in our Manifest file?

Comment: addition to above,those were Interview Questions..

Comment: i hope it wasn't a Pune based company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, as far as I know **there is no limit to the maximum number of Activites.**

Although, I would recommend that you do not exceed a typical amount of 10-15 Activities per app, due to usability reasons.

Furthermore, as far as I know you can only **start a new Activity using Intents.**

Comment: As far as i knew .only intent can start an activity..but this isn't the only way i guess..

Comment: Yes, that is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Activities can't be started by an other way, rather use of `startActivity()` method i.e. by using the intent, instantiating an activity by self is never advised and it should be left to the Android System itself.
2. There is no count on how many activities you can add to the manifest, so keep on adding them.

Comment: Still looking for the correct and in depth answer rather than "intents" & "keep adding them"

Comment: @minesh.. that's the only possible answer, as today I have come across this question twice, and one of the projects has more than 50 activities, also guy asking the same question got the very same reply from more than 5 people, so I am telling you what is viable, and I don't think there is any reason to write more, still I will try improving my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18591098/826657 here is the answer from the master himself !

Answer (score 0):

An Activity can only be started via an intent

There is no limit to the number of Activities in an Application other than practical ones having to do with file sizes, memory use, etc.